# Create one dataframe from multi csv files with different headers in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In Spark, with Pyspark, i want to create one dataframe (where the path is actually a folder in S3), which contains multi csv files with common columns and different columns. 
To say it more easily, i want only one dataframe from multiple csv files with different headers.

I can have a file with this header "raw_id, title, civility", and another file with this header "raw_id, first_name, civility".

This is my code in python 3 :

```
df = spark.read.load(
    s3_bucket + 'data/contacts/normalized' + '/*/*/*/*',
    format = 'csv',
    delimiter = '|',
    encoding = 'utf-8',
    header = 'true',
    quote = ''
)
```

This is an example of file_1.csv :

```
|raw_id|title|civility|
|1     |M    |male    |
```

And an example of file2.csv :

```
|raw_id|first_name|civility|
|2     |Tom       |male    |
```

The result i expect in my dataframe is :

```
|raw_id|first_name|title|civility|
|1     |          |M    |male    |
|2     |Tom       |     |male    |
```

But, what is happening is that i have all united columns but the data is not in the right place after the first file.
Do you know how to do this ?

Thank you very much by advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load each of them in a different dataframe and join them together on the raw_id column.

Comment: This is not what i want because i can have thousand of files and they can have common columns so i'll have duplicated columns.
And create a dataframe for each file in maybe hundred of folders is not possible.

Comment: I can't think of a good way to do this.  You can load the entire folder at once and all the files in it only if the schema of all the files is the same.  Otherwise data is going to be in the wrong column.  You can either preprocess the files so the schema is exactly the same, or manually join each file together.  Those are the two choices I see.

Comment: You are right, this is what i did. I arrange my data processing to have all files to have in final the same schema. And i was able to load it in one dataframe. Thanks again for your help.